# How to do "something" after uploading file with jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using this code: (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

$option = array(
    'upload_dir' => 'myurl',
    'SesId' => 1
);

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($option);
```

The script is working fine, but I want to do something after the file uploads:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

$option = array(
    'upload_dir' => 'myurl',
    'SesId' => 1
);

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {
    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $file->SesId = $this->options['SesId'];     
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index=null, $content_range=null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );

        if (empty($file->error)) {
        die();      
        }
        return $file;
    }
}

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($option);
```

The file uploads fine, but NEVER die() ???

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, is AFTER upload

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is "done", "fail", "always" event in order to do something after the upload. But it's client's side.

Comment: The file upload via PHP, but the answers is take it with JQuery. Finally the problem was that I'm call the wrong instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: I call the wrong instance.

The final line should by:

```
$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($option);
```